# ListView in Xamarin using RestApi

Tags: json, api, listview, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I'm enable to solve this error. I wanted to display `ListView` of API data which is in large amount.

**For example API contains this type of data :**

```
[{"id":"666","employee_name":"xyz","employee_salary":"123","employee_age":"23","profile_image":""}]
```

**Error screenshot:**
[image: screenshot of error]

**Class.cs which i made after converting JSON to c#**

```
 public class employees
    {

        public string id { get; set; }
        public string employee_name { get; set; }
        public string employee_salary { get; set; }
        public string employee_age { get; set; }
        public string profile_image { get; set; }

    }
```

**This is the XAML.cs file where `LoadData()` is using for calling API**

```
public async void LoadData()
        {
            var content = "";
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var RestURL = "MY API";  
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(RestURL);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(RestURL);
            content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<employees>>(content);
            ListView1.ItemsSource = Items;
        }
```

**This is the XAML file of Xamarin.Forms:**

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="White">
        <ListView x:Name="ListView1" RowHeight="60">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="8,0,8,0">
                            <Label Text="{Binding id}" TextColor="#000" FontSize="14" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding employee_name}" TextColor="#000" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: What is your problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: there are hundreds of existing tutorials and sample apps available that will show you how to load data from a remote API and display it.

Comment: Have you thinking of creating an object, and parse these json back to a list and then only set to the listview item source.

Comment: @Bruno Caceiro  kindly go through my code I listed above.

Comment: @Lee do you have any sample of code about what you're you saying because i'm beginner and I don't know how to parse

Comment: What is your error? You didn’t post the error.

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro I attached a picture above. check it

Comment: Can you check like what Junior Jiang showed? Double check whether the response is successfully retrieve and the JSON retrieved before you convert

Comment: From image show<<Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List. >>You need check the Json Data from api.Here is a solution you can refer to.(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49772027/cannot-deserialize-the-current-json-object-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First need to create a local model class :

```
public class TodoItem
{
    public string id { get; set; }

    public string employee_name { get; set; }

    public string employee_salary{ get; set; }

    public bool employee_age { get; set; }

    public bool profile_image { get; set; }
}
```

And in the `RestService` can use `TodoItem`:

```
public List<TodoItem> Items { get; private set; }

public async Task<List<TodoItem>> RefreshDataAsync ()
{
   Items = new List<TodoItem> ();
 // RestUrl = http://developer.xamarin.com:8081/api/todoitems
   var uri = new Uri (string.Format (Constants.RestUrl, string.Empty));
   try {
       var response = await client.GetAsync (uri);
       if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
           var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();
           Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <List<TodoItem>> (content);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
           Debug.WriteLine (@"ERROR {0}", ex.Message);
    }
    return Items;
}
```

And last where your listview `itemsource` can set as follow:

```
listView.ItemsSource = await RestService.RefreshDataAsync();
```

Note: Here is a [official sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WebServices/TodoREST/) you can refer to.

> I'm enable to solve this error, i wanted to display listview of API data which is in large amount

Showing large data in listview,here is a **paging show method**.After getting API data, saving them in local `CacheListData`.Not directly set it to `listView.ItemsSource` .And you need create a `ItemListData` to add data from CacheListData.Which the count of added data according to you once want to show.When listview scroll to bottom ,then show *Add More Swipe method* to reload next page data.

Generally, **Solution** is to cache lagre data to local first.Then get data a little by page to show.[Here is a solution link can refer to.](https://montemagno.com/load-more-items-at-end-of-listview-in/)

Comment: Jiang kindly check my code i above listed and tell me where I'm wrong and what I  have to do. Thanks

Comment: From image show<<Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List. >>You need check the Json Data from api.Here is a solution you can refer to.(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49772027/cannot-deserialize-the-current-json-object-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong endpoint, you should use this one, to retrieve a list of employees

```
 var RestURL = "http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees/";
```

You can check the [API documentation](http://dummy.restapiexample.com/)