# How to use PUT Method in Xamarin

Tags: json, api, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, put

**I am trying to use PUT Method to update my rest API, but its not working and not showing any error or exception.**

**Please help me through this issue.**

**And I am doing this in button event and textboxes(Entry) for input values:**

**Funtion:**

```
 private async void UpdateButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string aa = I.Text;
        string bb = N.Text;
        string cc = S.Text;
        string dd = A.Text;
        private HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var post = new check { id = aa, employee_name = bb, employee_salary = cc, employee_age = dd };
        var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(post);
        await client.PutAsync("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/update/"+aa, new StringContent(content));


    }
```

**Class:**

```
public string id { get; set; } 
        public string employee_name { get; set; }
        public string employee_salary { get; set; }
        public string employee_age { get; set; }
        public string profile_image { get; set; }
```

**XAML:**

```
 <StackLayout Margin="0,50,0,0">

        <Entry Placeholder="Enter your Id" x:Name="I"></Entry>
        <Entry Placeholder="Enter your name" x:Name="N"></Entry>
        <Entry Placeholder="Enter your salary" x:Name="S"></Entry>
        <Entry Placeholder="Enter your age" x:Name="A"></Entry>

        <Button Text="Update" x:Name="UpdateButton" Clicked="UpdateButton_Clicked"></Button>




    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: What does `its not working` mean exactly?

Comment: You make a request and do not check the response for its status. The content sent was serialized as JSON but no `application/json` content type header was included in the request

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks bro, can you please change my code or give a sample code for response status.

Comment: You already accepted an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54247670/5233410) that shows getting a response

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we have enough information to help you solve this problem. That being said, I would first verify that `content` contains valid JSON and that the JSON is in the format expected by the PUT endpoint. Next, I would test the endpoint manually using curl and the validated JSON from `content`.

This looks like C# to me, so I assume you're using Visual Studio. Since you're not getting any errors or exceptions, another idea is to step through each line using breakpoints.

Since the REST endpoint is on HTTP and not HTTPS, you could also use Wireshark to inspect the packets sent to and from the API.

Comment: yess I tried with breakpoints also and it hits with all the values I am giving it through textboxes . Content has valid JSON I checked it for many times.

Comment: Will you test the endpoint with curl and post the results?

Since you're on Windows, you may need to install cygwin.

Comment: Thanks Buddy I will try with this also and hopes for the best

Answer (score 0):

```css
Termin termin = new Termin();
termin.ID = userid;
    string url = "https://6a002c323e80.ngrok.io/";
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(termin);
    var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var result = await client.PostAsync(url+ "api/Termin/update", content);
```